# Override jquery autocomplete to add two extra result rows

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, overriding

I want to override the jquery autocomplete to add two extra result rows

Could you please post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data): the 'custom data' example may fit your needs.